# How do I extract all archives in the subdirectories of this folder?

Tags: windows, batch

How do I extract multiple archives in contained in subdirectories in a folder, outputting the results back into the folders where the archives are.

Answer (score 25):

Firstly, install [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Create a `bat` file in the root of the directory containing many subdirectories with archives inside. Then paste the following in:

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
        FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
            "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
        )
    popd
)
```

Launch the bat, and all rar's/zips will be extracted into the folder they are contained in.

**How does this work?**

> FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
>
> *For loop to loop through all folders in the current directory, and put the path into a variable `%%F`.*

> pushd %CD%
>
> *Put the current directory that we are in into memory.*

> cd %%F
>
> *Set the folder from variable `%%F` as the current directory.*

> ```
> FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
> ```
>
> *For all the `rar` and `zip` files in the current folder, do:*

> ```
> "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
> ```
>
> *Run 7-zip on the files.  Quotes are needed around `%%X` because some file names have spaces in them.*

> ```
> popd
> ```
>
> *Return to the previous directory that we previously stored in the memory.*

Hope this is useful to someone.

Answer (score 4):

I had problem running the script from Windows Vista. When I ran the code nothing happend. I needed to be administrator to be able to run the script. When I right clicked on the .bat file and "run as administrator" it didn't work because it for some reason started in the system32 folder (if I remember correctly). To solve this simply use the Windows Environment variable (explained here: [Windows Environment Variables](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)) %~dp0 to switch back to the directory that the script was run from.

```
@echo on
cd %~dp0

FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
pushd %CD%
cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x %%X
    )
popd
)
```

Make sure no *.rar or *.zip files are at the same level as the script. They should be one level down.

I hope this comment helped someone.

Comment: This worked fine for me. I had to change the path to "C:\Program Files (x86)" from "C:\Program Files" as I am running 64-bit Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.zip" |  while read filename; do unzip -o -d "`dirname "$filename"`" "$filename"; done;
```

Starts a recursive search at the current directory, finds all files ending in .zip, then pipes that into a loop.  For every file it finds, it runs an unzip command on the file with the output shunted to the file's directory.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above work, however, if you are running `Windows 64-bit` and `7-Zip 32-bit`, the correct path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip` for 7-Zip. Below is the script that worked for me.

```
@echo on
cd %~dp0

FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO ( pushd %CD% cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-zip\7z.exe" x %%X
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: If you have the 64-bit version of 7zip however, the correct path is: "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" as stated in the original answer.