# Extracting multiple password-protected archives located in multiple sub-directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch, archive, data-extraction

There is a folder that contains many folders and subfolders, and each of these contains any number of password-protected 7zip archives. The password is the same for all of them. These are single-layer archives (no archives within archives).

I am trying to extract all of them in a single command in such a way that:

1. Every file will be extracted to the directory in which its original archive was located without a subfolder being created for it,
2. Each original archive file will be deleted,
3. and the password will be input automatically by the command.

I already know this needs to be some kind of script since the 7zip context menu doesn't allow to do this AFAIK. However, I am not well-versed in command-line usage and would really appreciate if someone could provide a script I could copy-paste...

I already looked through a bunch of answers, including the following that describe a similar situation minus the password aspect:

- https://superuser.com/questions/240853/how-do-i-extract-all-zip-files-in-subfolders-using-7-zip-on-windows-7 (I Don't know how to use this)
- [How do I extract all archives in the subdirectories of this folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8092/how-do-i-extract-all-archives-in-the-subdirectories-of-this-folder) (I was able to figure out how to build in the password, but I am not sure how to tell it Y to all overwrites or how to add the delete the archive function)

Comment: **1.** `7z.exe -?` shows that `-y` switch means _assume Yes on all queries_. **2.** 7zip sets errorlevel upon an error. So you could add `if errorlevel 1 (call :error) else (del "%%~nxZ")` in your batch file (and add `:error` subroutine)…

Comment: 1. understood. 2. not understood... could you expand?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and share a code snippet you have so far.